# How do I change UIView Size?

Tags: uiview, swift, height, xcode6

I have trouble with modifying my UIView height at launch.

I have to UIView and I want one to be screen size * 70 and the other to fill the gap.

here is what I have

```
 @IBOutlet weak var questionFrame: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var answerFrame: UIView!
 let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

and

```
 questionFrame.frame.size.height = screenSize.height * 0.70
 answerFrame.frame.size.height = screenSize.height * 0.30
```

It has no effect on the app during run time.
I use autolayout but I only have margins constraints...

Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: questionFrame.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.7)
    answerFrame.frame = (0 , self.view.frame.height * 0.7, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.3)            Is somthing like this what you're after?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here you go. this should work.

```
questionFrame.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.7) 

answerFrame.frame =  CGRectMake(0 , self.view.frame.height * 0.7, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.3)
```

Comment: Just tried it on xcode 7.3. In order for this CGRectMake() to take effect, the UIView (my view is actually a subclassed from UIView) needs to have View->Mode set to "Redraw" or "Scale to Fit" and the CGRectMake() needs to be  in my subclass' drawRect() method. Otherwise the size definitions in the storyboard will take effect.

Comment: it's `x y width height` at the same time, it's better to use `userView.frame.size.height = 10
userView.frame.size.width = 10`

Comment: CGRectMake was renamed to CGRect.  The following code should work on newer Swift versions:       

questionFrame.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.7) 

answerFrame.frame =  CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: self.view.frame.height * 0.7, self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.3)

Answer (score 74):

This can be achieved in various methods in **Swift 3.0** Worked on Latest version **MAY- 2019**

**Directly assign the Height & Width values for a view:**

```
userView.frame.size.height = 0

userView.frame.size.width = 10
```

**Assign the CGRect for the Frame**

```
userView.frame =  CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:0, height:0)
```

***Method Details:***

> CGRect(x: point of X, y: point of Y, width: Width of View, height:
>   Height of View)

**Using an Extension method for CGRECT**

Add following extension code in any swift file,

```
extension CGRect {

    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {

        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)
    }
}
```

Use the following code anywhere in your application for the view to set the size parameters

```
userView.frame =  CGRect(1, 1, 20, 45)
```

Answer (score 33):

Swift 3 and Swift 4:

```
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Answer (score 20):

Hi create this extends if you want. **Update 2021 Swift 5**

**Create File Extends.Swift** and **add** this code (add **import foundation** where you want change height)

```
extension UIView {

    var x: CGFloat {
        get {
            self.frame.origin.x
        }
        set {
            self.frame.origin.x = newValue
        }
    }

    var y: CGFloat {
        get {
            self.frame.origin.y
        }
        set {
            self.frame.origin.y = newValue
        }
    }

    var height: CGFloat {
        get {
            self.frame.size.height
        }
        set {
            self.frame.size.height = newValue
        }
    }

    var width: CGFloat {
        get {
            self.frame.size.width
        }
        set {
            self.frame.size.width = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

**For Use (inherits Of UIView)**

```
inheritsOfUIView.height = 100
button.height = 100
print(view.height)
```

Comment: It's not possible to set the width and so on without a Initialization is only a get property !

Answer (score 2):

For a progress bar kind of thing, in Swift 4

I follow these steps:

1. I create a UIView outlet : `@IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!`
2. Then a property to increase its width value after a user action `var progressBarWidth: Int = your value`
3. Then for the increase/decrease of the progress `progressBar.frame.size.width = CGFloat(progressBarWidth)`
4. And finally in the IBACtion method I add `progressBarWidth += your value` for auto increase the width every time user touches a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Interface Builder:

1. Control-drag from a frame view (e.g. questionFrame) to main View, in the pop-up select ***Equal heights***.
2. Then go to size inspector of the frame, click edit ***Equal height to Superview*** constraint, set the multiplier to 0.7 and hit return.

You'll see that constraint has changed from ***Equal height to...*** to ***Proportional height to...***.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `questionFrame.frame.size.height= screenSize.height * 0.30` will not reflect anything in the view. because it is a get-only property. If you want to change the frame of questionFrame you can use the below code.

```
questionFrame.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: screenSize.height * 0.70)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is already a solution to this question, but I found an alternative to this issue and maybe it could help someone.

I was having trouble with setting the frame of my sub view because certain values were referring to its position within the main view. So if you don't want to update your frame by changing the whole frame via CGRect, you can simply change a value of the frame and then update it.

```
// keep reference to you frames
var questionView = questionFrame.frame
var answerView = answerFrame.frame

// update the values of the copy        
questionView.size.height = CGFloat(screenSize.height * 0.70)
answerView.size.height = CGFloat(screenSize.height * 0.30)

// set the frames to the new frames
questionFrame.frame = questionView
answerFrame.frame = answerView
```