# How do I make a UITextView expand over a UIImageVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview

I have a UIImageView and a UITextView. I need the UITextView to expand over the UIImageView when the UITextView is tapped. I am not sure how to do this.

From this [image: before expansion]

To this [image: after expansion]

Comment: Can you tell a bit more? What do you mean by expand over UIImageView? Do you want to make them have same points and size?

Comment: I added pictures for context

Comment: Do you use Auto Layout? How the text view and image view attached to main view? Can you tell this with some details? You created and add subviews by programmatically or with storyboard or xib fles?

Comment: I usually use auto layout, but I haven't set anything up, because I wasn't sure what to do. I thought of many things, but they didn't work so I was asking what way others have done this. The image view and text view would be in a storyboard in a view controller.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're trying to update the height of a UIView with a tap gesture. You'll need the following `IBOutlets`:

- An `NSLayoutConstraint`
- A `CGFloat` variable to update it that you
  can reach from your view controller to alter your
  `NSLayoutConstraint`'s constant
- A `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Additionally, your UIImageView will need to be behind the other views. You can just drag it to the top of the View hierarchy in Interface Builder. The top view is at the back of the hierarchy:

[image]

Here goes:

Create `IBOutlet`s for the view and the height of the UIView you want to animate:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bioView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bioViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

That is only a reference to the storyboard. If you want to alter `bioViewHeightConstraint`, you'll need to access its constant. So declare a variable for that:

```
var bioViewHeight: CGFloat! {
    /*
     Here we're using a property observer to execute code whenever
     this value is updated
     */

    didSet {
        print("stackViewHeight updated to \(bioViewHeight)")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: { 
            self.bioViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.bioViewHeight
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { _ in
            self.bioTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
            print("animation complete")
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see I put some animation code inside of this in `didSet`. So whenever you change `bioViewHeight`, `bioViewHeightConstraint.constant` will get updated.

Next, we configure a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with the following code:

```
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggleHeight(sender:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    bioView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

The tap gesture code goes in `viewDidLoad`.

Next, we have to write the handler for your taps. Here's the code for that:

```
func toggleHeight(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if bioViewHeightConstraint.constant == UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2 {
        // true
        bioViewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 30 // gives space for status bar
    } else {
        // false
        bioViewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
    }
}
```

That's the basic code that can do what you're trying to do. Here's a link to a [repo](https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/TapGesture) with the complete code.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I implemented something similar, but not nearly as nicely as you have.

Comment: Thank you it works great! Do you know how I could add that blue line and make it follow as the view rises and lowers?

Comment: I've never done anything w/ making non-rectangular views, but I think you'd want to google non-rectangular views in swift.I think the line at the top is just a border they colored blue.

Comment: Alright thanks! I drew a line, but maybe making the view a different shape would work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

- In your view controller layout (Storyboard or codes), make sure you put UIImageView under UITextView.
- In your IBAction where you handle UITextView tap event, just update its frame height to be equal with its controller height. (as seen on the screenshot).

  // one of several ways to update a view frame
      textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

You can find other methods to update UITextView size here: [How do I change UIView Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706565/how-do-i-change-uiview-size)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `Constrains`. All you need to change the `constant` value of specific `constraint` in the `Action` of `UITapGesture` on the `UITextView`.You can change the `Constraints` of `Top` of `TextView` and `height` of `TextView`.Try this!!

Comment: May I know the reason for the downVote?