# ForeceFully set view height to zero

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout

I have a view which has many `subview`. Height of view is depend upon height of `subViews`.But in a case I want view to be of height 0 regardless of its `subView` height. I to achieve that. 
for example there is a view called view and it has 2 `subView(image and label)` `view1` and `view2`.
constraint are like this.

```
 view1.top = view.top + 1
view1.height = 30
view2.top = view1.bottom
view.bottom = view2.bottom.
```

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Answer (score 9):

I think what you're are looking for is the heightAnchor.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622590-heightanchor

```
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the view.frame property? Here is an exapmple:

[How do I change UIView Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706565/how-do-i-change-uiview-size)